# datetime.strptime failure in CI

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.6

I have the following error which happens only in CI:

```
ValueError: time data '09.30.2019 17:50 EDT' does not match format '%m.%d.%Y %H:%M %Z'
```

Here's my test:

```
def test_extract_time_from_page(pjm_html):
    expected_time = datetime.strptime("09.30.2019 17:50 EDT", "%m.%d.%Y %H:%M %Z")
    res = demand.extract_time_from_page(pjm_html)

    assert res == expected_time
```

It passes locally. I'm not sure how this could be different running in a CI environment

Edit: I can reproduce this by changing my machine timezone to something other than EDT. Can you not use a timezone different than your current timezone with `datetime.strptime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue22377) with the `%Z` directive. The current documentation is confusing and there is a [pending request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/16507) to have the documentation revised. The pending documentation change explains the issue you are experiencing:

> Note that `strptime` only accepts certain values for `%Z`: `UTC`
>   and `GMT`, and what is defined in `time.tzname` for your own
>   locales. It will return a `ValueError` for any invalid strings. For
>   example, someone living in Japan will have `UTC`, `GMT` and
>   `JST` as valid values, but probably not `EST`.

Comment: I chose to strip the %Z value from the string and use pytz to localize it:

`expected_time = timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime(2019, 9, 30, 17, 25), is_dst=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with pytz lib. Compare pytz libs on your CI worker and locally. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21718343/10950272) you can find an explanation which points to [wikipedia list of timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) which says that EDT is a deprecated timezone. You can try updating your pytz lib on CI worker.